# How to store a previous value of a variable and update it for comparison?

Tags: c++

So there is a variable sensor.value which ranges anywhere from `1 - 1000`. How would I capture the `sensor.value`'s number initially so i can compare it to its future value.

For instance, say `sensor.value` is `5` I would want it to save that value for comparison then if it suddenly increased I want to perform an action.

Example ( this is for a game so the context is kind of fuzzy )

```
if ((command == 1) {
    static int sensorValue = sensor.value;
    if (sensor.value > sensorValue) {
        ///peformaction blah blah
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time getting it to re-update the value for `sensorValue` though.

Comment: Static variables are only initialized once, you never read the sensor a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You should update it after every comparison, try something like this:

```
static int sensorValue = 0;
void yourFunc()
{
    if ((command == 1) {
        if (sensor.value > sensorValue) {
            peformactionblahblah
        }
        sensorValue = sensor.Value
    }
}
```

Comment: Well when I do that regardless of the sensor.Value staying the same it continues to perform the action over and over and over. I cant tell if my operator is incorrect or maybe I should add more dependencies